# Объясните Python код

Tags: python

Число 20 выходит из листа, но я не понимаю как код после return-а работает

```
[value for value in sampleList if value != val]
```

почему до for пишется value, и как эта  строка работает и что делает? Объясните ребята, пожалуйста.
Знаю много других решений на эту задачу, но эту нашел и не могу понять, как он работает.

```
list1 = [5, 20, 15, 20, 25, 50, 20]

def removeValue(sampleList, val):
   return [value for value in sampleList if value != val]
resList = removeValue(list1, 20)
print(resList)
```

Comment: https://younglinux.info/python/feature/generators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данное выражение является генератором списка. С его помощью можно удобно создавать листы, опуская многострочное заполнение во внешнем цикле.

Генератор `[value for value in list]` перебирает все элементы списка `list` и добавляет их в возвращаемый список. А, например, генератор `[3 * value for value in list[::2]]` возвратит список состоящий из каждого второго элемента изначального списка, умноженного на три. Это просто базовый синтаксис генератора.

В конкретно вашем случае еще добавляется условие внутри цикла: `[value for value in list if condition(value)]`, где `condition` - либо какая-то логическая функция или операция сравнения. Простейшим примером такого генератора будет что-то такое: `[i for i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0]` - данный генератор возвращает список, состоящих из четных чисел в промежутке [0; 10), так как он перебирает все числа из данного промежутка и добавляет только те, которые кратны двум.

В вашем случае условие `condition` это `value != val`. То есть в возвращаемый список добавятся все элементы исходного списка, кроме тех, которые равны `val`.

Comment: Спасибо большое